# Multiplicative Inverse in Finite Fields

Tags: field-theory, inverse

I was looking at algorithms like the *extended eucledian algorithm* or *itoh-tsujii* with the goal to find a multiplicative inverse inside a prime (extension) field.

Why do we need these algorithms if $ $$a^{-1} = a^{q-2}$  with $a \in\mathbb{F}_q^{\times}$?

Comment: The EEA is also for infinite Euclidean rings. For finite fields, it is often faster than computing a high power modulo $q$.